# DirectX 11 - How to create a very simple 2D texture

Tags: c++, directx-11, texture2d

I am very new to Direct X 11. I want to create a simple 2d texture (of type ID3D11Texture2D). I have read document about [CreateTexture2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476521(v=vs.85).aspx) and I understand that:

**pDesc** is how we define the image.

**pInitialData** contains the array of bytes presents every pixel of the image texture

**ppTexture2D** is our result - the 2D texture for DirectX 11.

I want to create a very simple 2D texture: **a pink rectangle**. But I don't know how to create the array of bytes for the pink rectangle.
I have the code below:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC   Desc;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitialData;
ID3D11Texture2D*        pTexture2D;

Desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

BYTE* array;//How to have an array of Pink rectangle?

InitialData.pSysMem = array;
InitialData.SysMemPitch = 0;
InitialData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

m_device->CreateTexture2D(&Desc, &InitialData, &pTexture2D);//ID3D11Device m_device has been created before.
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you define pink as RGB (255, 174, 201) this creates a 1x1 pink texture:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> texSRV;
{
    static const uint32_t s_pixel = 0xffc99aff;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = { &s_pixel, sizeof(uint32_t), 0 };

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {};
    desc.Width = desc.Height = desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> tex;
    HRESULT hr = mDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, &initData, tex.GetAddressOf() );

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc = {};
        SRVDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

        hr = mDevice->CreateShaderResourceView( tex.Get(),
            &SRVDesc, texSRV.GetAddressOf() );
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
        // error!
}
```

> I'm using the recommended C++ smart-pointer for COM `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` in this code rather than 'raw' pointers which are harder to ensure proper reference counts. See [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) for more.

Of course, that's not typically how you create textures. You usually use image files, and more often than not use `DDS` files which have mipmap chains and use specialized texture compression formats.

See [How to: Initialize a Texture From a File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476904.aspx) on MSDN.

> A good place to start with DirectX 11 using C++ is [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) for it.

Comment: Note that creating single pixel textures can be useful to decrease the number of shaders by not differentiating between shaders with and without textures.

Comment: Um.. this was useful for me, but i'm color blind so that pixel was white lol.. but regardless...

I might suggest for someone who wants to manually set the R,G,B,A values you can do it like this. Below is a 50% transparent Yellow Square.


 const int RED = 255;
 const int GREEN = 255;
 const int BLUE = 0;
 const int ALPHA = 127;

 const uint32_t s_pixel = RED | (GREEN << 8) | (BLUE << 16) | (ALPHA << 24);

Comment: Note that [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) contains the ``DirectXColors.h`` header which provides values for all the [.NET Colors](https://www.99colors.net/dot-net-colors) in sRGB-colorspace. You can use ``XMColorSRGBToRGB`` to convert these constants to [linear colorspace](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-24-importance-being-linear).